# D lang GLFW error: X11: Vulkan instance missing VK_KHR_xcb_surface extension

Tags: glfw, vulkan, d

Пытаюсь запустить вулкан на языке D. Знаю что язык не популярный, но лично мне очень понравился, поэтому в личных интересах изучаю его, а за одно пытаюсь разобраться как работает вулкан. Может найдется тот, кто сможет мне помочь.

Написал минимальный код. В GLFW сделал callback на вывод ошибки при помощи метода `glfwSetErrorCallback` и там получаю ошибку под номером 65542:

> X11: Vulkan instance missing VK_KHR_xcb_surface extension

Получаю ее на этапе вызова метода `glfwCreateWindowSurface`.
P.S. Сам метод отрабатывает без ошибок, но возвращает null, а в консоли выводит сообщение выше.

Пишу на linux. Для компиляции использую dub.
Вот настройки из dub.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "bindbc-glfw": "~>1.1.0",
        "erupted": "~>2.1.98",
        "xcb-d": "~>2.1.1"
    },
    "libs": [
        "glfw3",
        "xcb-ewmh"
    ],
    "versions": [
        "GLFW_33",
        "BindBC_Static"
    ]
}
```

Сначала подумал, что чтото с импортами начудил, но вроде все нормально должно быть.
Вот импорты:

```
import xcb.xcb;

import bindbc.glfw;

import erupted;
import erupted.vulkan_lib_loader;
import erupted.platform_extensions;

mixin Platform_Extensions!KHR_xcb_surface;
mixin(bindGLFW_Vulkan);
```

Проверил vulcan info. Вроде как расширение у меня установлено. Может быть я какуюто библиотеку забыл добавить или в коде что забыл?

```
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.3.250


Instance Extensions: count = 22
===============================
    VK_EXT_acquire_drm_display             : extension revision 1
    VK_EXT_acquire_xlib_display            : extension revision 1
    VK_EXT_debug_report                    : extension revision 10
    VK_EXT_debug_utils                     : extension revision 2
    VK_EXT_direct_mode_display             : extension revision 1
    VK_EXT_display_surface_counter         : extension revision 1
    VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace            : extension revision 4
    VK_KHR_device_group_creation           : extension revision 1
    VK_KHR_display                         : extension revision 23
    VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities     : extension revision 1
    VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities    : extension revision 1
    VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities : extension revision 1
    VK_KHR_get_display_properties2         : extension revision 1
    VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2 : extension revision 2
    VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2       : extension revision 1
    VK_KHR_portability_enumeration         : extension revision 1
    VK_KHR_surface                         : extension revision 25
    VK_KHR_surface_protected_capabilities  : extension revision 1
    VK_KHR_wayland_surface                 : extension revision 6
    VK_KHR_xcb_surface                     : extension revision 6
    VK_KHR_xlib_surface                    : extension revision 6
    VK_LUNARG_direct_driver_loading        : extension revision 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Оказалось, что я забыл про метод `glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions`. Как только его корректно реализовал - проблема ушла

P.S. По просьбе добавляю более развернутый ответ.
У glfw существует следующий метод [glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__vulkan.html#ga99ad342d82f4a3421e2864978cb6d1d6).

Обращу внимание, что для доступности этой функции необходимы следующие импорты:

```
import bindbc.glfw;

import erupted;
import erupted.vulkan_lib_loader;
import erupted.platform_extensions;

mixin Platform_Extensions!KHR_xcb_surface;
mixin(bindGLFW_Vulkan);
```

Как написано в документации

> This function returns an array of names of Vulkan instance extensions required by GLFW for creating Vulkan surfaces for GLFW windows. If successful, the list will always contain VK_KHR_surface, so if you don't require any additional extensions you can pass this list directly to the VkInstanceCreateInfo struct.

Тоесть она выводит список расширений, необходимый для вулкана. А в данном случае в ней будет содержаться VK_KHR_surface.
Поэтому в данном случае в мой код просто необходимо было добавить

```
uint required_extension_count;
const(char)** required_extensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&required_extension_count);
if (!required_extensions) {
    throw new Exception("glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions failed");
}

for (uint i = 0; i < required_extension_count; i++) {
    extensions_names[extensions_enabled++] = required_extensions[i];
}
```

Перменная `extensions_names` в моем случае содержит в себе список расширений, которые после будут добавлены в структуру `VkInstanceCreateInfo`, который после будет передан в `vkCreateInstance`.

Тоесть этот код должен быть до того как вы создаете vulcan instance.

Вот пример структуры `VkInstanceCreateInfo` в моем случае:

```
VkInstanceCreateInfo inst_info = VkInstanceCreateInfo(
    VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO,
    null,
    0,
    &app,
    0,
    null,
    extensions_enabled,
    cast(const(char*)*)extensions_names,
);
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. Например, добавьте, как его надо "корректно" реализовать.